# How to set a global chart.js tooltip label callback

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to globally set the number formatting for different Chart.js types, including: bar, line, horizontalBar, radar.

The following works for everything except horizontalBar:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label =  function(tooltipItem, data, index) {
  var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
  if (label) {
      label += ': ';
      }
  label += tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
  return label;}
```

This fails for horizontalBar, because the axis changes from y to x. Changing `.yLabel.` to **`.xLabel.`** in the above thus works for horizontalBar, however, fails for the others.

I tried setting horizontalBar defaults separately with

```js
Chart.defaults.horizontalBar.tooltips.callbacks.label =  function(tooltipItem, data, index) {
  var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
  if (label) {
      label += ': ';
      }
  label += tooltipItem.xLabel.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
  return label;}
```

which gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed is not a function"

I could also not figure out how to get the chart type within `function(tooltipItem, data, index) {}` otherwise one could set the y/xlabel conditional on the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways, the first one is by checking if the value is a number, this way you can get the xAxes value if its a horizontal bar. Fallback in else for if both axis are text values

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem, data, index) {
    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
    if (label) {
        label += ': ';
    }
    if (typeof tooltipItem.yLabel === 'number') {
        label += tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    } else if (typeof tooltipItem.xLabel === 'number') {
        label += tooltipItem.xLabel.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    } else {
        label += tooltipItem.value
    }
    return label;
}
```

You can also check if the value from the tooltip is a number and use that instead of the labels, this will require a typecast so it will be more resource intensive:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem, data, index) {
    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
    if (label) {
        label += ': ';
    }
    if (Number(tooltipItem.value)) {
        label += Number(tooltipItem.value).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
    } else {
        label += tooltipItem.value
    }
    return label;
}
```